# Error: Request failed with status code 400. missing headers? error in backend?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm sending a POST request using axios to my localhost(this case, it's 10.0.0.2:8000) in React Native (android simulator) and I'm getting 400 error from Django RESTful Framework Backend.

This is my action creator

```
export const doAuthLogin = ({ username, password }) => dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/login/`, {
    username,
    password
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // Save Token post is Already await.
    AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_token', response.token);
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.token });
  })
  .catch(response => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGIN_FAIL, payload: response.non_field_errors });
  });
};
```

This is error message from Remote Debugger JS. It's just a console.log(response) from catch from axios.post.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:538)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:260)
    at MessageQueue.js:101
```

Error message in console,
    [17/Aug/2017 14:14:10] "POST /rest-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 400 40

And this is a part of settings.py,

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'profiles',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '10.0.2.2',
    'localhost'
)
```

I'm thinking I might have an error in action creator. Missing headers or...

This error doesn't give me any hint more than 400 so I'm totally lost. Can you help me with this problem, please?

Thanks

Comment: what parameters are you expecting in djagno? Maybe try to send a request first with a tool like postman, and then try it with code

Comment: What is the response body?

Comment: It works in Postman ( http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/ with username and password)

Comment: response body is just username and password. username can be either email or username.

Comment: what's allowed hosts setting in your project

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.0.2.2', 'localhost']

Comment: try to make it `['*']` and see if it works

Comment: by the way, I'm using expo. does it matter? um

Comment: I made it ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] and still gives me 400.

Comment: Is it showing any error message besides 400 bad request on your django console

Comment: It's showing this line of message whenever I make a POST request to it. [17/Aug/2017 14:35:02] "POST /rest-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 400 40
with red color

Comment: It's not showing any error message besides 400 bad request on django console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for commenting guys. 
The problem was that I was actually sending undefined to username and password.

`{username, password } -> (username, password)`

This question was very silly question, this code is perfect. No CORS error, correct response body, and correct allowed hosts. Actually your comments convinced me that I may have a problem in React code. I consoled log variable in each line.

Thank you so much! Now I can sleep

Comment: this.props.doAuthLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)